# Get SQL Logs/Error as output of the script

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am working on a web application. In this application we are using inlilne SQL query for database operation. The reason behind is , we are having   number of different databases with same database structure. Also we need to work on different databases. If we proceed   with stored procedure, there may be a chance of exception, if we  miss any script to execute to any of the database.
In the exiting application, it is  inserting the employee details using different database calls.  That is , one call to insert the details to EmployeeMaster table , another call is to Address table, next  one is to qualification  table etc.
Now I  am making this multiple database calls to single call.   I would like  get all the exception/log details from  the   executed script.
I am familiar with RAISERROR. But this way we can only get the single error details.
I want to get the message like

```
1   emp100 Created
2   Details Inserted to Address table
3   Qualification1 not exist In the Qualification Master table
```

I know we can achieve it using a  temporary table.
Is there any better way to solve this issue?

Any help would be appreciable.

Regards,

Ranish

Comment: Are you able to use a batch script ?

Comment: "I know we can achieve it using a temporary table." How exactly can you do that?  Any detailed logging like what you describe will be platform-dependent, and man providers do not have logging at that level.